# Differentiate which keyboard (not key) was pressed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events, keyboard-events, keycode

I have 2 USB keyboards plugged in. How can I determine which one was pressed?

I can use `keyCode` for my events but I don't see something about getting a read on which keyboard was used.

Gamepads, on the other hand, have an index for which gamepad in the navigator's list was used. I'm looking for something like that.

Comment: As others have noted, there is no standard way to do this right now. However, newer versions of Chrome do support an experimental [`InputDeviceCapabilities`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputDeviceCapabilities) API. It's extremely minimal right now, and I wasn't able to really do anything with it along the lines of what you want. However, [the W3C docs on it](http://wicg.github.io/InputDeviceCapabilities/#dom-uievent-sourcecapabilities) are pretty good, and make it seem as though the functionality will expand in the future along the lines of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I determine which one was pressed?

You can't. [`KeyboradEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) doesn't contain such information.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do this. This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959989/capture-the-events-of-2-or-more-keyboards-in-javascript-web-browser).