# Finding out which keyboard generated a key event in javascript

Tags: javascript, keyevent

Is there some way to determine which keyboard connected to a device sent a particular key event in JS? For example, a laptop with a USB keyboard will happily honour keypresses on both keyboards but I cannot seem to find a way for the browser to tell me which source a key event came from so I can filter based on that (e.g. for player 1/2 input filtering for a browser based game, keyboard vs. "virtual instrument" for a browser based composing tool, etc.)

I couldn't find anything in the key events specs on MDN that suggests this is possible, but I'll be more than happy to take on any creative hack that makes this work "despite" rather than "thanks to" the spec.

Someone [did ask this question back in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959989), and while its answer suggests using the gamepad API as workaround, it's now 2018 and three years of changes to JS APIs means that this question is worth reasking, in order get an answer based on the current state of the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture the events of 2 or more keyboards in JavaScript/Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959989/capture-the-events-of-2-or-more-keyboards-in-javascript-web-browser)

Comment: @ShubhamGupta that's a resolved question from 2013 and will not get answers that are likely to be even remotely relevant in 2018 - five years is too long for useful answers on specialised APIs in browser-land.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it is already possible, but if would try something like that, i would study the WebUSB Api:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web
https://wicg.github.io/webusb/

Not so easy, but seems possible

Comment: I'm considering using the gamepad API, so that simultaneous input can be registered with the help of a keyboard->virtual gamepad tool, but there might be other options as well. I'd like to stay away from solutions that only work in a single browser (I don't particularly feel like building a "chrome site", rather than a "web site" =)

Comment: You have a good point. Taking this in consideration, i would use the gamepad API too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at present.

WebUSB won't allow access to HID devices, and WebHID won't allow access to devices (including keyboards) that are already supported by high-level APIs.

I've started a topic at the WICG incubator: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/identify-which-of-multiple-keyboards-an-event-came-from/3416